# Cross Selling Matrix - In Snowflake

Tags: sql, matrix, pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to build a cross selling matrix with the following structure pivoted as seen below where X is the % of frequency in a basket with the other product:

[image: Cross Sell Matrix]

I need to pivot this data in excel or another tool afterwards so I assume the query in Snowflake needs to output tabular dataset ready for pivoting, and I am struggling with its logic.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT FCT.TRANSACTION_ID,
   PRD.PRODUCT_TYPE,
   COUNT(DISTINCT FCT.PRODUCT_ID),
   COUNT(DISTINCT FCT1.PRODUCT_ID)
FROM TRANSACTION_ORDERS FCT
     INNER JOIN DIM_PRODUCT PRD ON FCT.PRODUCT_ID = PRD.PRODUCT_ID
     LEFT JOIN FACT_TRANSACTION_ORDERS FCT1 ON FCT.TRANSACTION_ID = FCT1.TRANSACTION_ID
                                            AND FCT.PRODUCT_ID != FCT1.PRODUCT_ID
GROUP BY FCT.TRANSACTION_ID, FCT.PRODUCT_ID, FCT1.PRODUCT_ID
```

Is the joining even correct? Or should I be doing a cross join? Also, how to capture percent frequency of both products in the same basket?

Many thanks!

**EDIT:** I am trying to capture the frequency of different product types appearing in the same basket.

The values are the same for combinations in both directions. ProductType1 intersection with column ProductType2 is the same value as column Product Type1 row ProductType2.

When in a basket cross analysis they should vary. It is not the same per direction. In other words, baskets with **ProductType1 may have ProductType2 X % of the time but baskets with ProductType2 should have ProductType1 with Y%** of the time.

Comment: Sample data -- or at least the table layouts -- would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - The only columns that are relevant to this problem should be TRANSACTION_ID, PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_TYPE.

Answer (score 1):

You want a self join.  I would expect the products to be in the same *order*, but you seem be using the same *transaction*.  In any case, this is the structure of the query:

```
WITH TP AS (
      SELECT T.*, P.PRODUCT_TYPE
      FROM TRANSACTION_ORDERS T JOIN
            DIM_PRODUCT P
            ON T.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID
     )
SELECT TP.PRODUCT_TYPE, TP2.PRODUCT_TYPE,
       COUNT(DISTINCT TP.TRANSACTION_ID) as NUM_ORDERS
FROM TP JOIN
     TP TP2
     ON TP2.TRANSACTION_ID = TP.TRANSACTION_ID
GROUP BY TP.PRODUCT_TYPE, TP2.PRODUCT_TYPE;
```

If this were per order, you would just change the `ON` clause in the outer query to use the order id.

Note that this uses `COUNT(DISTINCT)` rather than `COUNT(*)` because a transaction/order could have multiple products of the same type.  Presumably, you want that counted only once.

EDIT:

If you want to divide by the number of transactions that have either product type (which makes sense to me), then I would approach this as:

```
WITH TP AS (
      SELECT DISTINCT T.TRANSACTION_ID, P.PRODUCT_TYPE
      FROM TRANSACTION_ORDERS T JOIN
            DIM_PRODUCT P
            ON T.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID
     )
SELECT TP.PRODUCT_TYPE, TP2.PRODUCT_TYPE,
       COUNT(*) as NUM_ORDERS,
       ( MAX(CASE WHEN TP.PRODUCT_TYPE = TP2.PRODUCT_TYPE THEN COUNT(*) END) OVER (PARTITION BY TP.PRODUCT_TYPE) +
         MAX(CASE WHEN TP.PRODUCT_TYPE = TP2.PRODUCT_TYPE THEN COUNT(*) END) OVER (PARTITION BY TP2.PRODUCT_TYPE) -
         COUNT(*)
       ) as Num_Orders_Either,
       ( COUNT(*) * 1.0 /
         ( MAX(CASE WHEN TP.PRODUCT_TYPE = TP2.PRODUCT_TYPE THEN COUNT(*) END) OVER (PARTITION BY TP.PRODUCT_TYPE) +
           MAX(CASE WHEN TP.PRODUCT_TYPE = TP2.PRODUCT_TYPE THEN COUNT(*) END) OVER (PARTITION BY TP2.PRODUCT_TYPE) -
           COUNT(*)
       ) as ratio
FROM TP JOIN
     TP TP2
     ON TP2.TRANSACTION_ID = TP.TRANSACTION_ID
GROUP BY TP.PRODUCT_TYPE, TP2.PRODUCT_TYPE;
```

This calculates the total orders containing both products using the sum of the orders with either product minus the number with both.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This answer produced the number of orders, which is great, but how would I produce % of this occurrence?

Comment: @choloboy . . . You would divide by something.  It is not clear what, because your question doesn't specify the logic and it is not obvious.

Comment: There is one thing that is unclear to me. The values are the same for combinations in both directions. ProductType1 intersection with column ProductType2 is the same value as column Product Type1 row ProductType2. When in a basket cross analysis they should vary. It is not the same per direction.

In other worsd, baskets with ProductType1 may have ProductType2 X % of the time but baskets with ProductType2 should have ProductType1 with Y% of the time. It should not be the same, for all cases.

How can I modify your second query to account for that?

Comment: @choloboy . . . You *question* doesn't specify what the calculation is.  I just added a reasonable guess.

Comment: Your guess was very reasonable, thank you. The calculation was perfect. I was just wondering about the bidirectionality of the matrix and calcs. Updated the question. I am just wondering how to update your reasonable guess to account for bidirectionality of product frequency in baskets.